# input that triggers a javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, input

I did a bunch of buttons on a navbar. These buttons can trigger different articles or lesson in two languages from side to side.

Later, I found that this is troublesome when I try to search for a specific article. So I decided that I'll add an input text bar to take my input and trigger a javascript function that I want.

I simplified the numbers in this post, but this is the core of the script. I named the functions with 4 digits numbers MMDD so I wish that I can type in a box 0312 and the function 0312 get executed.

However, I cannot seem to get it to work. Is that even possible in javascrip？ If not what approach do you recommend?

```js
function fr01() {
  document.getElementById("fr01").innerHTML = "text here will appear in french"
}

function en01() {
  document.getElementById("en01").innerHTML = "text here will apear in english"
}

function myFunction01() {
  fr01();
  en01();
}

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

  function 'x'
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()">
<button onclick="myFunction01()">CHAPTER01</button>
```

the top part works perfectly fine and in realtime, when I press the corresponding button it shows both sides, when I try to type in number I get this error message

```
myFunction is not defined at HTMLInputElement.oninput
```

Didn't I already define it in the top portion?

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: What do you expect `function 'x'` to do?

Comment: remove the function 'x' and it works ok

Comment: I now believe I forgot to add to it' `myFunction'x'`

I want to assign a function that has a variable name which is based on the input I give it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do call functions dynamically based on for example a text value, then you could create a *map* which connects a string to a function. An object is very similar to this. It has properties, which can be strings, and a value, which can be functions.

```
const actions = {
  'foo': function() {
    // Do something.
  }
};
```

With this pattern you can create a list of valid options and the connect the corresponding functions that come with the list.

Now let's say you have a string. With that string you can select a function from the object with the bracket notation.

```
const string = 'foo';
const action = actions[action];
```

If a value is found, then `action` will now be a function. Otherwise it will be `undefined`.

The snippet below demonstrates this principle.

```js
function omg() {
  console.log('omg');
}

function bark() {
  console.log('bark');
}

const actions = {
 '0312': function() { // Regular function.
   console.log('Hello')
 },
 '0420': () => { // Arrow function.
   console.log('Wow')
 },
 '1360': () => console.log('Vroom'), // Arrow function variation.
 '1337': () => { // Arrow function that calls two other functions.
   omg();
   bark();
 },
 '7331': [omg, bark] // Array with function references.
};

const form = document.querySelector('#form');
const actionField = document.querySelector('#action');

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  const selector = actionField.value;
  const action = actions[selector];
  
  if (typeof action === 'function') {
    action();
  }
  
  if (Array.isArray(action)) {
    action.forEach(subAction => {
      subAction()
    });
  }
  
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <label for="action">Try me (0312, 0420, 1360 and 1337 will work)</label>
  <input type="text" id="action" />
  <button type="submit">Execute</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Now theoretically, can this trigger two functions? or since because I have the two functions in a parent function it wouldn't matter?

Thanks a lot btw!

Comment: Well, it could, if you would have an array of functions and loop over the array and call each function. Or, like you said, use a single function to call two, or more, other functions.

Comment: instead of the console.log(''), can I write a function?

Comment: Yes you definitely can, it already are functions. I've added some more variations on how to write them down `() => {}` is basically the same as doing `function() {}`, but with some minor differences. You could write anything you want the function to do inside the brackets `{}`.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','`
there is a bug there somewhere in my code, ｂｕｔ　I'll find it. Ｉ　ｔｈｉｎｋ　ｙｏｕｒ　ｃｏｄｅ　ｉｓ　ｅｘａｃｔｌｙ　ｗｈａｔ　Ｉ　ａｍ　ｌｏｏｋｉｎｇ　ｆｏｒ！